# Link between sign up box on website & mailchimp list

Tags: css, html

I can't find the answer elsewhere on here so thought I'd ping this out to you all :)

What I'm trying to do is add a sign up box to our website with the following code however I want to add everyone who subscribes to a list in Mailchimp. So these need to talk. I have tried using their subscription form & extracting the form action & inserting into my own however no joy as of yet...

HTML

```
    <div id="fh5co-subscribe">
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="row animate-box">
            <form action="//mintapple.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=24e473a8271c8679b25d07ad4&amp;id=3e4d074650" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Subscribe">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue seems to be;

```
//mintapple.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=24e473a8271c8679b25d07ad4&amp;id=3e4d074650" method="post
```

Do I need an API to insert to get this to link to my list?

Any help appreciated!!

Dale